# Database with MS JET after migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-access

I am migrating a bunch of sites which each use an Access database (or whatever an MDB file is). If I try to load the site, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied
```

If I rename the MDB file, I get a complaint that the file does not exist, which makes sense. If the file is named correctly, the site tries to load for about 30 seconds or so, and then just fails with the above message. During this waiting period, I can see a lock file being created (and then at some point removed). The MDB file and it's parent dir have full permissions granted to all users. Given that the lock file is successfully created and removed, I don't think that this is a "real" permission issue.

The OS is Windows Server 2003 SP2. I am not sure about much more detail on it's config wrt Access databases. I also don't know what version it is expected to be.

VB code in question:

```
set oConn=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
DSNtemp="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\fullPathGoesHere\db\sitedb.mdb"
oConn.Open DSNtemp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code seems to be using the Jet OLE DB Provider, the error message mentions the OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. Make sure you really are using the Jet Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another part of the website code that is trying to access a SQL Server database? Check for an include file that makes a SQL Server database call (looks like the site maybe using ASP).